# CSS transform when using a css animation transforms differently only in Safari

Tags: css

This is pretty hard to explain so I made a codepen. Try opening it in Chrome and in Safari and click in the codepen viewport to see the difference:
https://codepen.io/matt_o_tron_5000/pen/gOMaKmY

Basically, we have this dot that follows the cursor around with the help of some javascript. A CSS animation makes it gently grow/shrink at all times, and when you click the dot reacts by shrinking substantially.

In Chrome and Firefox, when you click, the dot shrinks to the center, where the mouse pointer is located. But in Safari, it shrinks to the upper left corner. I found that by removing the CSS animation, this is resolved. But I can't figure out *why*.

Any idea how I can fix this behavior in Safari?

Aaaaaand apparently I can't post this unless my codepen link is "accompanied by code". So here's some code.

// HTML

```
<span id="custom-cursor"></span>
```

// CSS

```
#custom-cursor {
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  width: 6rem;
  height: 6rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0) scale(1);
  transition: 0.1s ease-out;
  transition-property: width, height, transform;
  animation: growshrink 4s infinite;

  &.clicking {
    width: 1rem;
    height: 1rem;
  }
}

@keyframes growshrink {
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0) scale(1);
  }

  50% {
    transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0) scale(1.3);
  }

  100% {
    transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0) scale(1);
  }
}
```

// Javascript

```
(function () {
  var follower, mouseX, mouseY, positionElement, timer;
  follower = document.getElementById('custom-cursor');
  console.log(follower);
  mouseX = event => { return event.clientX; };
  mouseY = event => {return event.clientY;};
  positionElement = event => {
    var mouse;
    mouse = {
      x: mouseX(event),
      y: mouseY(event),
    };

    follower.style.top = mouse.y + 'px';
    follower.style.left = mouse.x + 'px';
  };
  window.onmousemove = event => {
    if(!timer){timer = false;}
    var _event;
    _event = event;
    return timer = setTimeout(() => {
      return positionElement(_event);
    }, 5);
  };
}).call(this);

$(document).on('mousedown', function() {
  $('#custom-cursor, #imghover-cursor').addClass('clicking');
});
$(document).on('mouseup', function() {
  $('#custom-cursor, #imghover-cursor').removeClass('clicking');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Browsers render code differently.... one can either update its code so that it behaves like one wants in the 'supported browsers' for the project OR go a user-agent sniffing way/per browser-type approach I don't recommend that and I never do that just because there's almost always a way to do it with option #1 which is much simpler, cleaner and easier [changing the library you use and/or tweaking your existing code].

When I suggest 'changing the library for animation' I mean more specifically use an open-source community-vetted one like GSAP. https://greensock.com/gsap/

But if you want to go down the rabbit hole, please start here :

https://github.com/WhichBrowser/Parser-PHP